# How to register the time a product stays at a facility?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know how long a product stays at a facility.

It is for a main ground handler at an international airport.

The dataset looks similar to this:

| Airline Code | Flight | Flight Act. DateTime | Type | Number | Owner | Flight Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | AB1234 | 10-10-2021 | ABC | 12345 | AB | Outbound |
| AB | AB1234 | 13-10-2021 | ABC | 12345 | AB | Inbound |
| AB | AB1234 | 15-10-2021 | ABC | 12345 | AB | Outbound |
| CD | CD3456 | 9-10-2021 | ACE | 54321 | CD | Inbound |
| CD | CD3456 | 14-10-2021 | ACE | 54321 | CD | Outbound |
| CD | CD3456 | 15-10-2021 | ACE | 54321 | CD | Inbound |

Code I mixed and matched.

```vb
Sub MultipleSearch()

Sheet9.Activate

Dim ULD As String:
Dim ULD_Procedure As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rgSearch As Range
Dim ILastCol As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim ColumnResult As Variant
Dim Result As Variant
Dim DateFlight As Variant

With Sheet9

    LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
            
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        
        ULD = Cells(i, 2).Value

        Sheet3.Activate
       ' Get search range
        Set rgSearch = Range("I:I")
        Set cell = rgSearch.Find(ULD)
    
        ' Store first cell address
        Dim firstCellAddress As Variant
        firstCellAddress = cell.Address

        ' Find all cells containing set ULD number
        Do
            Sheet9.Activate                  
            ILastCol = (1 + Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
                                              
            'Adjust CellAdres to only give me the correct Row number
                            
            RowResult = cell.Address
            Result = Replace(RowResult, "$I$", "")
                            
            Sheet3.Activate
            DateFlight = Cells(Result, 4).Value
                            
            Sheet9.Activate
            Cells(i, ILastCol).Value = DateFlight
                            
            Set cell = rgSearch.FindNext(cell)

        Loop While firstCellAddress <> cell.Address
    
    Next i

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Not found"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

This code gets the dates the ULDs enter the system or left, and with the use of "basic" Excel formulas I can measure the time between ULDs. However not in the correct order, this is due to that not all ULDs enter the system in Inbound. Some are already here and the first record of those ULDs is outbound. Also some ULD miss registration on outbound or inbound. So saying they follow a standard order of inbound outbound inbound outbound is incorrect.

The solution I am looking at is pasting the date focused on inbound and outbound.

How I want the result sheet to look.

| ULD Number | First entry | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Outbound |  | 10-10-2021 |  | 11-10-2021 | 12-10-2021 | 14-10-2021 | 17-10-2021 | 19-10-2021 |
| 12345 | Inbound | 08-10-2021 | 08-10-2021 | 12-10-2021 | 15-10-2021 |  | 16-10-2021 | 17-10-2021 | 20-10-2021 |

How it currently looks.

| ULD Number | First entry | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Outbound | 10-10-2021 | 11-10-2021 | 12-10-2021 | 14-10-2021 | 17-10-2021 | 19-10-2021 |  |  |
| 12345 | Inbound | 08-10-2021 | 08-10-2021 | 12-10-2021 | 15-10-2021 | 16-10-2021 | 17-10-2021 | 20-10-2021 |  |

I'm not asking you to write my entire code but if you can make an outline of a possible formula / piece of code that I can use.

Comment: This would be an easy task to accomplish with an SQL query. Use a database instead of Excel, or do some research on how to SQL query an Excel sheet.

Comment: Don't you want one line per ULD Number ? Why 2 for 12345 ?

Comment: @CDP1802 In my real data set every ULD has its own line. Due to confidentiality i can't share the real figures. This was a fault on my behalf. Thx for your sharp eyes however!

Comment: `DateFlight = Cells(Result, 4)` suggests the Column D has the date/time so ULD is Column B, is this correct ? Does date/time show a time if you format the column dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm ?

Comment: |Airline Code |Flight |Flight Sched. DateTime| Flight Act. DateTime| Week Number| Flight Type| Uld Handling Type| Type| Number| Owner| Uld Pieces| Uld Weight| Pallet / container/Bulk| Uld_Status| ULD_RCVD| Flight Direction| |Awb Destination| Days at facility

Comment: @Corn026 did you check my edited answer again? I still believe sorting will solve your issue.

Comment: @CDP1802 I can't figure out how to put a table in a reaction but Yes my dates have a format dd/mm/yyyy/ hh:mm:ss, My ULD number are in Sheet3 Collomn I. An array with Unique numbers however is displayed sheet9 Collomn B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort your data (at the same time) by:

1. Number (ascending)
2. Fligth Act. DateTime (ascending)
3. Flight Direction (ascending) , so on the same date `Inbound` comes first

and use the following formula in a new column in row 2 and pull it down

```
=IF(G2="Inbound",IF(AND(E3=E2,G3="Outbound"),C3-C2,"no outbound"),"-")
```

[image]

It will show you for every `Inbound` how many days the flight stayed until its `Outbound`. If there is no `Outbound` it will mark it as `no outbound`.

So you can only calculate the stay time of the flight if it has an `Inbound` AND `Outbound` if one of them is missing you cannot calculate it.

To make statistics on that times you can use functions like `AVERAGEIF` for example to get the average stay time of a flight.

---

Edit according comment:
You said:

> 1, 2, 3, 4 arrive on the 12th but on the 14th ULD; 1, 3, 5, 6 depart. The ULDs; 2, 4 may not leave the facility until a much later, for example the 30th. Now downtime on ULD; 1, 3 = 2 days, but ULD; 2, 4 has 18 down days.

So this would look like

[image]

After sorting (by number, date and direction) and using above formula I get:

[image]

Comment: Hey Peh, Thx for your answer. Unfortunately, this won't work for my data set. Because not every ULD goes straight back. So it can happen that ULD; 1, 2, 3, 4 arrive on the 12th but on the 14th ULD; 1, 3, 5, 6 depart. The ULDs; 2, 4 may not leave the facility until a much later, for example the 30th. Now downtime on ULD; 1, 3 = 2 days, but ULD; 2, 4 has 18 down days. This is where the real problem occurs :/   . I will look into your other SQL solution. Thx!

Comment: @Corn026 but sorting by ULD does the trick! Because everything of ULD 1 stays together then. Just sort in the order I suggested in my answer. This way Inbound and Outbound of one ULD will stay together in lines next to each other. Sorting ensures this. Give it a try. If you think it does not work please show a set of data that shows that it will not work, so I can get into it.

Comment: @Corn026 See my edit where I showed the solution of the scenario you created in your comment.

Comment: Hey @Peh i tried your answer but can't figure out why excel won't give me any data in return. Give me few minutes to figure it out. Then i send you screenshot so you also know more :)

Comment: @Peh please look at following link, or the edited one in my initial question. I can't anymore today and wil try to see what is wrong tomorrow. Thx for your possible solution however. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMK6A.png

Comment: @Corn026 well you used an entire different formula which is wrong, so of course that cannot work. Use exactly the formula I showed and only adjust the addresses (if needed).

Comment: @Peh That is the problem they both don't work. Even i adjust the language correctly. I will look into it tomorrow. I have been staring at my desk for way to long today.

Comment: For if you wanted to know, your solutions works! I maybe overengineered the formula but otherwise I couldn't get it to work. Thanks for helping! https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8lbp.png

Comment: @Corn026 Great! Thx for the response.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly I don't even think you need to go to the trouble of using VBA to solve it.

Pivot tables/lookups and some date/time maths should be able to solve it for you.

If you really want to use VBA though you want to start thinking more like a programmer/developer.

Understand the problem, break it down into very small problems and solve all those very small problems in isolation.

So first up you want your data off the sheet and into memory (ideally you only want to interact with the sheet twice, once at the start to extract data and once at the end to output your results).

So you want a method that extracts data from the sheet and places it into something to represent the flights, I would opt for a class object for each flight so it can be identified by it's unique code.

So if the method starts with an empty collection, and parses through the sheet looking at each line, it would first check if the flight exists in the collection by checking to see if the unique code on the sheet exists, if it doesn't then create a new instance of a flight class using the unique code, if it does then get a hold of the existing flight class from the collection.

Then extract the the data from that row into the flight object. Your flight object class will no doubt need a collection within it to hold all the possible inbound/outbound detail.

Once you have the data extracted you can sort it within each of the class objects if needed (so you need a function to accept the data from the object, sort it properly and then pass it back as a sorted collection).

Once you have transformed the data you will need to carry out your calculations on in, so again a function the data can be passed to in order to get the required result.

Finally you will need an output method to take the data from each object and output it to the sheet in the desired format.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Also worth remembering though, if you create a program to solve this rather than using excel functions on the sheet, then it also requires someone with the appropriate knowledge to maintain the program (changes in the format of the input data would cause the extract methods to either fall over or collect data incorrectly, which will cause problems further through the program, best case scenario it falls over, worst case scenario it still processes to the end, nobody realises it is doing it incorrectly and you are now believing total nonsense produced by the tool).

Comment: Hey @TheGlovner, I don't fully understand your explanation or it doesn't coffer the whole problem. I can easily get 1 date out of my database. It becomes more difficult when the value reoccurs 6 or 7 times. The difficult part for me currently is to orden those entries by inbound/outbound per ULD, not per flight. Currently, I feel like I have bitten off more than I can chew :?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I suspect you may be using a hammer here to crack a nut, but I'm not sure of your reasons for doing so, if it's an exercise to learn programming using VBA then go ahead and try to work through the problem in small sections, if it's to solve the actual problem you've been given without any need to use a particular tool then I'd go with Pᴇʜ's solution approach below (although it may need a little tweaking  to do what you want.

Comment: Peh's solution seems promising. It is a real problem that i need to solve however because there are storage capacity problems. I just thought VBA would help me but seems not to \o/

Comment: Oh it could certainly solve the problem posted, not sure it's going to help with Storage Capacity issues though since you are still going to end up with data in an excel spreadsheet at the end of it. To address storage you could export the output to a different sheet and then save this as a csv which is essentially a text file and as such far smaller than an .xlsx. Or as others have said a database may be a smarter solution and would also address storage capacity issues, excel really isn't meant for recording huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data on date/time and build a dictionary using the ULD numbers as keys and a collection of date/times as values. Loop through the collections writing date/times to either an even or odd column according to direction of travel. Data on sheets(1), report on sheets(2).

```vb
Sub MultipleSearch2()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
   
    Dim dict As Object, key, entry
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)  ' data
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(2)  ' output
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rng = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow, lastcol)
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    
   ' sort sheet by date/time
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add key:=ws.Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' get list of uids (colI) build collection inbound/outbord
    Dim ID As String, dt As String, inout As String
    For r = 2 To lastrow
        ID = ws.Cells(r, "I")
        If Not dict.exists(ID) Then
            dict.Add ID, New Collection
        End If
        ' add to collection
        dt = Format(ws.Cells(r, "D"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
        inout = Left(ws.Cells(r, "P"), 1) ' I or O
        dict(ID).Add inout & "_" & dt, CStr(r)
    Next

    ' output results
    r = 2
    With wsOut
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1:B1") = Array("ULD Number", "First Entry")
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        For Each key In dict.keys
            ID = CStr(key)
            .Cells(r, 1) = ID
            c = 3
            n = 0
            For Each entry In dict(ID)
                ' inbound odd, outbound even
                If Left(entry, 1) = "O" Then
                    If c Mod 2 = 1 Then c = c + 1
                    ' extend header
                    If .Cells(1, c - 1) = "" Then
                        .Cells(1, c - 1) = "Inbound"
                        .Cells(1, c) = "Outbound"
                    End If
                Else
                    If c Mod 2 = 0 Then c = c + 1
                        If .Cells(1, c) = "" Then
                            .Cells(1, c) = "Inbound"
                            .Cells(1, c + 1) = "Outbound"
                        End If
                End If
                wsOut.Cells(r, c) = Split(entry, "_")(1) ' remove I_
                ' first entry
                n = n + 1
                If n = 1 Then .Cells(r, 2) = .Cells(1, c)
                c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```